# Solution of the equation $dy/dx = 3yx^2/(y^3+3y^4)$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How do I find solution of the equation $dy/dx = 3yx^2/(y^3+3y^4)$? The variables can't be separated, the equation is not homogeneous and the equation can't be put in $dy/dx + Py = Q$ form. How then do I solve it?

Comment: Why have you not cancelled the factor of $y$ in the second term ? ... Are you missing some brackets 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{3x^2y}{\color{red}{(} y^3+3y^4 \color{red}{)}}
\end{eqnarray*}
would be much easier.

Comment: Why not begin by simplifying it to $dy/dx = 3 (x^2 / y^2) + 3 y^4$?  You can then find an [integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor).

Comment: @avs in our syllabus the only IF taught has been for dy/dx + Py = Q form

Comment: This is a separable equation.  $(y^2 + 3 y^3)\; dy = 3 x^2 \; dx$.

Comment: @Hema, if the parenthesization suggested by Donald Splutterwit is correct, then (1) I think you need to practice algebra so as to get your use of parentheses correct (skipping the parentheses marked in red produces a completely different ODE), and (2) the equation can be solved by [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
It is separable:

$$\frac{y^{3}+3y^{4}}{3y}dy=x^{2}dx$$

So for $y \neq 0$, solve $\left(\frac{1}{3}y^{2}+ y^{3}\right) dy = x^{2}dx$